# How to force SCNView to render a new frame?

Tags: ios, scenekit

Is there a way to force SCNView to render a new frame on demand if there is no animation inside the scene? If the scene is static SCNView renders exactly once and then only after something changes.

Usually this makes sense, but I am working together with the Vuforia augmented reality framework which requires me to render a new frame every time it processed a new video frame from the camera. I worked around this issue by creating my own UIView with a CAEAGLLayer which renders the SceneKit content using an SCNRenderer. This works great, but I am curious if there is a way to do this with SCNView so I can avoid directly touching OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update**

As of iOS 11.0 and macOS 10.13 the [`rendersContinuously`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/2867339-renderscontinuously) property on `SCNView` is the preferred way to force the view to continuously render frames.

---

**Previous answer**

you can set its `playing` property to `YES`

Comment: Thanks, that was quick. I can't believe I overlooked this property. But this is not exactly what I am looking for, I need a method to immediately render a single frame.

Comment: SCNView is tied to the display link, which means that it presents 60fps and is synchronized with refresh of the display. If you want to decide when the scene is drawn, then you must use a SCNRenderer.

Comment: I don't see a `playing` property on SCNView - https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnview, was it removed?

Comment: it's on the https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenerenderer protocol, to which `SCNView` conforms

Comment: This also solved my rendering stutter problem: there used to be a lag between node transform matrix update and the updated node actually being drawn.

Answer (score 2):

You can increment the `sceneTime` like so:

```
sceneView.sceneTime += 1
```

It will then render a single frame.

Comment: Not exactly the solution I was looking for, but this solved my problem anyway

Answer (score 1):

As a UIView, you can use the same mechanism to request an update as you would any other UIView: `[_sceneView setNeedsDisplay];` However, as pointed out, this shouldn't be used as the primary way to drive updates as it would not be synced with the display.